# Unexpected values in the buffer at Java code

Tags: java

Simple program from DEITLE's book , read 5 integers and the program should print line containing that number of adjacent asterisks .i.e (if num = 5 the output *****) .
I have tested the same solution in c++ and it worked fine . yet, here the buffer is holding strange values (50 ?) .
I think the problem is in using the buffer   , however i want to know why this is happening?

```
   /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication1;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
/**
 * Program that reads five numbers and print starts equal to each number 
 *
 * @author Hassan
 */
public class JavaApplication1 

{


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       int num ; 
       java.io.InputStreamReader  ins= new InputStreamReader(System.in);
       java.io.BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader (ins);

       try
       {


       for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
       {
           System.out.println("Please Enter a number");

           num = bfr.read(); 

       System.out.print(num);


             for(int j=0;j<num;j++)
                {   System.out.print("* ");  }
                  System.out.println("\n");


       }    
       } 

       catch(Exception E )
       {System.out.println(E.getMessage());  }



    }
}
```

EDIT :the problem has been solved , yet the program -out of 5 inputs -is reading 3 only i.e its reading input and ignoring the next one 
[image]

Comment: First read about BufferedReader and InputStreamReader class. You can consider that it open a "input pipe" where you can "insert" some data (in your example of int type). If the data is read incorrectly an exception is caught, I think in your example more correctly it is IOException class. E is an instance of Exception class, and getMessage() is a method of this class. However, in a modern approach you use Scanner class for input different type of data from keyboard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're reading a byte, which will just be the ascii value of the first available character. 50 is '2' in ascii. You probably want to read, and parse, a number entered as text.

If you use `readLine()` instead of `read()`, into a `String`, you can then use `Integer.parseInt()` to get the real value.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse yeah, that :)

Comment: @HSN That seems like a new problem. Here's a version of your code with the suggested changes, which seems to work: http://ideone.com/MI9GOh

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't compile:

1. write comments using `//` not `\\`
2. your curly brackets are not aligned which confuses and could lead to errors
3. When you write a comment - make sure to close the brackets in a new line (otherwise it is part of the comment)

Fix these three issues and your program will work.

**Update**:
JasonD is right, change:

```
num = bfr.read();
```

to:

```
num = bfr.read()-48;
```

and it'll work. The reason is that you're reading a character and '0' is 48 in ascii, '1' is 49 etc, so if you're expecting an input in the range 0-9 you should subtract 48 and it'll work.

If you want to handle numbers > 9 you'll have to use `readLine()` and parse the input `String`.

Comment: Maybe i just mis-formated the code while copying it , because it compiled and worked at Net beans . i will edit it now

Comment: @HSN Fixing these three issues made it compile and run on my machine